# win_shell completing command but not ending process

Tags: powershell, ansible

I'm learning Ansible and am running into something I haven't seen a good reference for anywhere -

I have a .ps1 on my target machine that I want to run via Ansible, while passing it a variable as well. My playbook for it is pretty simple:

```
---
- name: run stuff
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    force_all_hosts: false
  tasks:

  - name: run mounter script
    win_shell: C:\folder\file.ps1 -password (ConvertTo-SecureString "{{vault_pw}}" -AsPlainText -Force)
```

The contents of the .ps1 work when I run them manually local to the Windows machine, so I know the actual commands work. When I run the playbook it works as well - the Powershell script runs succesfully and the changes are made - but the actual task never completes so the playbook can't finish.

I added a "< NUL" to the end of the win_shell line to force a message that said the return code wasn't 0 - the RC was 1 - but then I updated Ansible to 2.8 and now the "<" character is reserved so I can't recreate the return code failure anymore.

Is there a way to force the return code, and filter if it's <= 2 or something? Or better yet, is there another way to ensure the job ends other than using async/poll since that causes the play to report that it failed?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you show us the PowerShell code.

Comment: It's not a terrible idea, but what deterred me from focusing on the PS portion is that it works when run remotely via a remote Powershell session.

That, and there's a lot of proprietary info in there that I'd have to strip out before sharing so I'd like to avoid it if I can. Is there a scenario where the PS script could run fine on its own but not when called via Ansible - yet the issue lies in the PS script itself??

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the async option in ansible?
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html

Comment: I mentioned it in passing in my very last sentence, but using async works - it just causes the play to report that it failed when in fact it didn't. I may have to go down the rabbit hole of registering the return and then use conditions to filter out the failure - but I'd like to avoid that if I can at all.